# VBA creating a for loop to copy data into separate text files

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I've created a code which will save data from 2 columns of my excel spreadsheet when a button is clicked. I want to create a For loop which will save multiple text files. Each text file will have the data from column B, but, for the second column, will loop through from column C to column N. I.e. the first text file will have the data from columns B and C, the second text file will have data from columns B and D, the third will have columns B and E etc.

This is the code I have so far, without the loop

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wbText As Workbook
Dim wsReports As Worksheet

Set wbText = Workbooks.Add

Set wsReports = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temps_protected_profile")

With wsReports

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    wbText.Sheets(1).Range("B1") = "<TEMPERATURES>"
    wbText.Sheets(1).Range("B2") = lRow - 2

    .Range("B3:B" & lRow).Copy wbText.Sheets(1).Range("B3")
    .Range("C3:C" & lRow).Copy wbText.Sheets(1).Range("C3")


End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With wbText

    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Cell1.txt", _
    FileFormat:=xlText
    .Close False

End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

In terms of naming each text file, I'd just like to add a number at the end of the name each time, i.e. the first text file will be called 'Cell1', the second will be called 'Cell2.'

If anyone can help me with any of this, that'd be majorly appreciated! I'm completely new to VBA and I'm really struggling to even start the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having your files I didn't test it, but I believe it should work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wbText As Workbook
Dim wsReports As Worksheet
Dim i as Long
Set wsReports = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temps_protected_profile")    
For i = 3 to 14
Set wbText = Workbooks.Add

With wsReports
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    wbText.Sheets(1).Range("B1") = "<TEMPERATURES>"
    wbText.Sheets(1).Range("B2") = lRow - 2

    .Range("B3:B" & lRow).Copy wbText.Sheets(1).Range("B3")
    .Range(.Cells(3,i), .Cells(lRow,i)).Copy wbText.Sheets(1).Range("C3")

End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With wbText

    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Cell" & i - 2 & ".txt", _
    FileFormat:=xlText
    .Close False

End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could follow this code (see comments for explanations)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim firstColumnRng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temps_protected_profile") 'reference "source" sheet
        Set firstColumnRng = .Range("B3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)) ' set referenced sheet range to be copied as first column
        For Each cell In .Range("C3:N3") ' loop through referenced sheet columns C to N
            With Workbooks.Add 'add and reference a new workbook
                With .Sheets(1) ' reference new workbook first sheet
                    .Range("B1:B2") = Application.Transpose(Array("<TEMPERATURES>", firstColumnRng.Rows.Count)) ' write two cells in one shot with Array() function
                    firstColumnRng.Copy .Range("B3") ' copy "source" sheet first column values and paste them into referenced sheet from cell B3 downwards
                    cell.Resize(firstColumnRng.Rows.Count).Copy .Range("C3") ' copy "source" sheet current loop cell column values and paste them into referenced sheet from cell C3 downwards
                End With

                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Cell" & Format(cell.Column - 2, "00") & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText 'save referenced workbook
                .Close False 'close referenced workbook without saving changes
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```